# IE EDGE Intranet API requests are all get requests, no request body, no response body,

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

Browser :IE EDGE

System: WINDOWS 10

There is no problem with requesting the extranet API

In EDGE's debugging tool, any Intranet API request you see will become a get request with a state of 200, no request body, no response body, no type,size is (from memory cache).

Nothing is returned

Either domain or IP

No problems with chrome

Comment: I used the axios interceptor to see that there was nothing wrong with the pre-send configuration

Comment: It doesn't work when I set $.ajax's cache=false

Comment: Try to install the latest updates for your windows 10 OS and again try to check for the issue. If issue persist than try to inform us which exact version of Edge you are using for making this test. Also try to provide any sample code or detailed steps to reproduce the issue. we will try to check for the issue.